# 3D modeling: any production-quality GPU renderers out there?

Tags: gpu, rendering, 3d-graphics, 3d-modeling

Are there stable and production-quality renderers out there, which use the GPU?
*(I mean pluggable renderes for suits such as 3ds max, Maya, Blender, ...)*

I am aware that preview functionality often uses the GPU, but I was hoping to accelerate the final (real) rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. They are two different kind of technologies. I am afraid we. Are still stuck with big expensive render farms for a while.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
**Sorry, found out that only the preview-renderer is GPU-accelerated :(**

I found out that [**V-Ray 2.0**](http://www.chaosgroup.com/en/2/vray.html) claims to support this. It is for 3ds max and Maya.

I have not tried it and I don't know to which extend it is "faster" thanks to GPU rendering, and if it's renderings are reproducible among different GPUs (which is an *important* criteria for final production rendering).

I hope to get this information somewhere soon.

Answer (score 0):

iRay is GPU-accelerated and is quite photorealistic, especially when using the iray plugin: http://blog.irayrender.com/post/83815598089/iray-material-plugin-updated-for-3dsmax-2015